# SQL Why put winner at the end while order by year?

Tags: sql

From the following table, write a SQL query to find the Nobel Prize winners for the subject not started with the letter 'P'. Return year, subject, winner, country, and category. Order the result by year, descending.

Sample table : nobel_win

[image]

Solution:

```
SELECT * 
 FROM nobel_win 
  WHERE subject NOT LIKE 'P%' 
   ORDER BY year DESC, winner;
```

I don't understand why the solution put `winner` at the end. It seems that `winner` is not required.

Comment: In theory, as you said, winner is not required to answer the question. In practice, we should not only order result by `year DESC` because the result will be random in order each time we run the query, so often we would use sorting like `ORDER BY year DESC, category, subject, country, winner` (or omit country).

Comment: order by `winner` is to show order in the column if multiple data have the same `year`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely, the `winner` column was tagged to the end of the `ORDER BY` clause to break the tie should 2 or more records happen to have the same year.  If that be the case, then simply ordering by year descending might leave all records belonging to a given year appearing unsorted.  The query you posted above resolves this by ordering all record within a given year by the `winner` name.

Comment: Makes sense. As Pham mentioned in the comment, we would use sorting like `ORDER BY year DESC, category, subject, country, winner`. Then why do we put `winner` only but omit the others?

Comment: It really depends on the intentions of he who wrote the query.  Sans this information, I can only speculate.